# Authenticating with Google OAuth

Tags: php, oauth, protected-resource

Im currently working on an OAuth authentication system for my site that allows the login of users via the Google API.

Im working with Codeigniter 2.0.2 and I do not have PECL OAuth compiled on my server, so im having to use raw php to do this.

I have go as far as authenticating the user with Google, and getting back the **oauth_token** and **oauth_token_secret** for that user.

But after endless reading of the protocol I still cannot find how that **oauth_key** and **oauth_token_secret** to gain access to the other API to collect the following information:

- Email Address
- Profile Picture
- Full Name
- Location

Here is the current code that im using to authenticate:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class OAuth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('google_oauth',array(
            'key'       => '*REMOVED*',
            'secret'    => '*REMOVED*',
            'algorithm' => 'HMAC-SHA1'
        ));
    }

    public function login()
    {
        //Get Request Token
        $response = $this->google_oauth->get_request_token(
            site_url("/oauth/collect"),
            'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'
        );

        //Store temp
        $this->session->set_flashdata('g.token.secret', $response['token_secret']);

        //Redirect
        redirect($response['redirect']);
    }

    public function collect()
    {
        $token_s = $this->session->flashdata('g.token.secret');
        if(!$token_s)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid auth session data, please rety your login');
            redirect();
        }

        $oauth = $this->google_oauth->get_access_token(false, $token_s);

        /*Check the data is valid*/
        if(!isset($oauth['oauth_token']) || !isset($oauth['oauth_token_secret']))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Unable to authecticate securly with Google, please try again');
            redirect();
        }

        $token = $oauth['oauth_token'];
        $secret = $oauth['oauth_token_secret'];

        //Will Store Here
    }
}
```

And im currently using a slightly modified version of this authentication class:

https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-YouTube-API-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/google_oauth.php

Comment: still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried experimenting with [Google OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php) ? Its useful for working out what API Feeds you can access and building valid request strings.

Here's a list of Google APIs you can access: [Google API Directory](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html)

Hope that helps